# C - recursive function that accepts pointers as parameters problem

Tags: c, function, recursion

I've been given a problem in which I have to write a function that accepts two parameters (both are pointers, the first one points at the beginning of an array and the second one points to the place in memory after the last element of the array)

The function has to be called from the first element of the array to the one in the middle,  and then from the middle element to the one at the end, and then the function should return the value of those two which is bigger.

```
double max_element(double *p1, double *p2)
{
    double from_first_to_middle = max_element(p1, (p1 + p2) / 2 + p1);

    double from_middle_to_last = max_element((p1 + p2) / 2 + p1, p2);

    if(from_first_to_middle > from_middle_to_last)
    {
        return from_first_to_middle;
    }
    else
    {
        return from_middle_to_last;
    }
}
```

But when I try to run this code it gives me the error

```
error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘double *’ and ‘double *’)
```

So then I thought that I should dereference these pointers as I cannot do these operations with the addresses they point to, but it still does not work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: The only valid arithmetic operation on pointers is subtraction, as it might give an offset. Any other operation is meaningless (and is not allowed - see http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p2). You can do something like `p1+(p2-p1)/2` instead, as here the second operand for addition will have an integer type (`ptrdiff_t`).

Comment: Can you please reformulate your specification and question please? It is unclear what you mean by "The function has to be called from the first element of the array to the one in the middle, and then from the middle element to the one at the end, and then the function should return the value of those two which bigger.

". Also, the second pointer points to something after the last element in the array? That sounds dangerous to me.

Comment: @John: you usually have to use this convention to simplify aritmetics i.e. `p1 == p2` means empty, `p1 + 1 == p2` means single item, so `p2 - p1` yields 1 although `p2` is pointing outside the array. Unless you dereference it, it isn't UB.

Comment: @Groo Sure, if it isn't dereferenced, it's all good. But how can you be sure p2 is after the last element in the array? I won't go any further into this. The question needs refactoring.

Comment: Not sure why this question is downvoted. Looks a good one to me. the code needs a bit of formatting though.

Comment: @John, there is no way for the function to be sure that `p2` points just after the last element of the (sub)array of interest.  And that's largely irrelevant, because it's a constraint on *calling* the function.  So is the fact that `p1` must be a valid pointer to a `double` -- the function cannot reliably check that, either.  In general, functions promise to provide a certain behavior *provided that* their arguments are valid, for a function-specific definition of "valid".  What they do otherwise is typically unspecified or even undefined.

Comment: @John (the first one) I am guessing you start with `double * array; int len;` and simply call `max_element(array, array + len);`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for the clarification. My initial understanding what that the author wanted to perform the operation on two "unrelated" arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are not integers.  There are only a few arithmetic operations defined for them, and pointer + pointer addition and pointer / integer division are not among them (what would they mean?).  You may add an integer to a pointer to get another pointer, offset from the original by the specified number of target objects.  Conversely, you can subtract one pointer from another to obtain an integer representing the number of target objects between the two pointed to.  There are restrictions on both of these operations, but those should not interfere with what you need to do.

You can use the above kinds of pointer arithmetic operations together with some integer(-only) arithmetic to compute midpoint pointer needed for your function.  Details are left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

```
double max_element(double *p1, double *p2)
{
    double from_first_to_middle = max_element(p1, (double *)((size_t)(p2 - p1) / 2) + p1);

    double from_middle_to_last = max_element((double *)((size_t)(p2 - p1) / 2 + 1) + p1, p2);

    if (from_first_to_middle > from_middle_to_last)
    {
        return from_first_to_middle;
    }
    else
    {
        return from_middle_to_last;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `max_element` is expecting p\ointers. Why would you pass it `size_t`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. My bad, fixed.

Comment: Still, casting `ptrdiff_t` into `size_t` doesn't look like a good idea. Why do you need this cast at all? I would imagine you can get rid of all of the casts.

Comment: BTW, looks like the logic is broken. You pass the difference instead of a pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. size_t can safely represent pointer types. Also, we have a precondition that p2 is greater than p1. See https://www.viva64.com/en/a/0050/ section on Safety of ptrdiff_t and size_t types in address arithmetic

Comment: See my very first comment under the question on how to do it properly and with no casts.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Will leave the casts for the author. It could be written the way you mentioned: (p1, p1 + (p2 - p1) / 2); and (p1 + (p2 - p1) / 2 + 1, p2)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not to be end, because your return have some problem.
if `p1 + 1 == p2`,then the recursion keep recursing. You should add a line

```
if ((p1+1) == p2)
 return *p1;
```

in the beginning.

```
double max_element(double* p1， double* p2)｛
    if ((p2 - p1) <= 0)
        exit(1);
    if ((p1+1)==p2)
        return *p1;
｝
```

Answer (score 0):

If, instead of using `p1` and `p2`, you were to use pointer names that match your `from_first_to_middle` and `from_middle_to_last` variable names, things might become clearer:

```
double max_element(double *first, double *last)
{
    if (last - first == 1)
    {
        return *first; // base case of our recursion
    }

    double *middle = first + (last - first) / 2;

    double from_first_to_middle = max_element(first, middle);

    double from_middle_to_last = max_element(middle, last);

    if (from_first_to_middle > from_middle_to_last)
    {
        return from_first_to_middle;
    }

    return from_middle_to_last;
}
```

Although with regular numbers, `(p1 + p2) / 2` is the same as `p1 + (p2 - p1) / 2`, that logic doesn't hold with pointers due to lack of pointer addition.  Even then, your formula: `(p1 + p2) / 2 + p1` is also wrong for regular numbers.